# JavaFX TableColumn.setCellValueFactory() throws null pointer

Tags: java, javafx, fxml

I got an issue with initializing one of my Tables. 
I first start my Program and want to load Data later.

I got the following setup:

Main.java: initializes program and loads all the controllers, this works fine.
It also holds the functionality to load data, if done so it is being stored in a List.

`TableViewController.java` controlls one Tab of my program containing a `TableView`.

`setMain` is called in my Main.java when the program is started.

```
@FXML
private TableView<MyObject> tableView;
@FXML
private TableColumn<MyObject, String> columnOne;
@FXML
private TableColumn<MyObject, Integer> columnTwo;
@FXML
private TableColumn<MyObject, String> columnThree;

public void setMain(Main main) {
    this.main = main;
    tableView.setItems(main.getMyObjectObservableList());
}

public void updateContents() {    
    columnOne.setCellValueFactory(value->value.getValue().getType());   
    columnTwo.setCellValueFactory(value->value.getValue().getTotal().asObject());
    columnThree.setCellValueFactory(value->value.getValue().getTrend());
}
```

I'm getting

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
```

in row of `columnOne.SetCellValueFactory;`

I used Eclipse debugger and set a breakpoint at the `updateContents`, my `TableView` object is filled with data, from being loaded.

Why is the exception thrown?

EDIT1:

FXML:

```
<TableView fx:id="tableView">
                 <columns>
                    <TableColumn fx:id="columnOne" prefWidth="411.0" text="title" />
                    <TableColumn fx:id="columnTwo" maxWidth="335.0" minWidth="-1.0" prefWidth="188.0" />
                    <TableColumn fx:id="columnThree" maxWidth="335.0" minWidth="-1.0" prefWidth="188.0" />
                 </columns>
              </TableView>
```

Loading FXML:

```
    public void initTable() {
    try {
        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
        loader.setLocation(Main.class.getResource("view/Table.fxml"));
        AnchorPane table = (AnchorPane) loader.load();

        Tab t = new Tab();
        t.setText("Table");
        t.setContent(table);

        mainTabPane.getTabs().add(t);

        tableViewController = loader.getController();
        tableViewController.setMain(this);

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Update Contents:

```
public void loadData(File[] files) throws IOException {
//loading data here
myObjectObservableList.add( new MyObject(params));
TableViewController.updateContents();
}
```

Comment: Could you post the snippet from the fxml containing the `TableColumn` creations, the part of the java code where you're loading the fxml and the part where you're calling `updateContents`?

Comment: @fabian done :)

Comment: `tableViewController` and `TableViewController` Seem to be 2 different variables. Why? Are you sure both variables contain the same controller instance? Also it's probably simpler to use `TableView.refresh` (JavaFX 8u60+). Furthermore if `myObjectObservableList` set as `items` of the table, there should be no need to refresh the table manually...

Comment: @fabian
Its the same variable I made a misstake when I edited the names it for Stackoverflow.
I didn't use TableView.refresh with it it works! Thanks so much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question was answered by fabian in one of the comments to the question itself.

Thanks!